# Example of discrete set

Tags: general-topology, order-theory

Please I need examples of discrete set and non discrete set... am a little confused over this expression.

I am thinking of discrete as a finite set but found from another article that, its not necessarily a finite set.

If I can just have two examples, I will be fine..

Thanks

Comment: The set of integers is the standard example of discrete infinite set.

Comment: [First result on Google](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteSet.html) // [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space)

Comment: Think about the definition you are using for "discrete" and see if that helps to guide your approach.

Comment: Yea, I thought as much but when we now have to talk about non discrete set.. Can there be non-discrete set?

Comment: The reals or the rationals are non-discrete.

Comment: Oh, stop the downvotes!  It was a legitimate question by someone trying to understand a concept.

Comment: Def'n . A set $S$ is discrete iff $\forall  p\in S\;(\;p\not \in \overline { S\backslash \{p\} }\;).$ Discrete subsets of the reals include $S_1=Z ,$ $ S_2=\{1/n :n\in N\} ,$ $ S_3=\{\log n :n\in N\}$ and many more.

Comment: That's a good definition but it's not very intuitive to a novice.  Not in the closure of all but, means it's not a limit point of all but.  Which means there's a neighborhood of p that has no other points of the set.  This is true for all points.  So a discreet set is one in which every point has a "discrete" area separating it from all other points (albeit these areas can be infinitismally thin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integers.

{$1/n| n \in \mathbb Z$}

Actually, *any* countable set of real numbers that can be put in order so that $....  a_i < a_{i+1} < a_{i+2} < ....$ will be discrete.

Discrete set means every point, x, has an open neighborhood in which x is the only point in the set. For any orderable countable set of real numbers indexed so that ... $a_i < a_{i+1} <$ .... then one can find a small neighborhood around each $a_i$ that only contains $a_i$ and no other point in the set.

Examples of non-discreet sets would be sets were at least one point is such that *every* neighborhood contains other points int the set.

For example.  The Rational numbers aren't discrete because *every* interval around a rational will contain and infinite number of other rationals.  The reals aren't discrete either.

The set {$1/n| n \in \mathbb Z\} \cup \{0\}$ is *not* discreet because for every interval $(-h, h)$ around 0, will contain points $1/n \ne 0$.

Comment: Thanks @fleablood for the answer... you got what am looking at